# Can't get hostednetwork started in Windows 8 x64

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, network-shares, network-adapter, wireless-access-point

OS: Windows 8 x64. Mobo: ASUS P8Z77-V Deluxe.

I can't start an Access Point with my computer. I tried everything.

I tried netsh wlan commands from cmd (with Admin privileges) and it returns the following error:

> C:\Windows\system32>netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow
>
> The hosted network mode has been set to allow.
>
> C:\Windows\system32>netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid=** key=** keyUsage=persistent
>
> The SSID of the hosted network has been successfully changed. The user key passphrase of the hosted network has been successfully changed.
>
> C:\Windows\system32>netsh wlan start hostednetwork
>
> The hosted network
> couldn't be started. The parameter is incorrect.

After that I tried to start an Access Point via ASUS WiFi Engine. A tool provided by ASUS specifically for my motherboard. It didn't work.
Then i tried other third party programs like Wi-Host, Connectify, VirtualRouterPlus. Nothing worked.

In device manager when i click "show hidden devices" under network adapters I have both "Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter" and "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter" **enabled** but they aren't shown in "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections" no matter what I do.

I tried to disable my network adapters and then enable them again with no luck.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled both my network adpaters drivers and ASUS Wifi Engine. Still nothing.

I also tried to use the Internet Connection Sharing method but the result is always the same, no access point.

I'd like to point out that everything else works fine, I can even connect via Wifi without an issue.

I have updated all my drivers and my Wifi Broadcom card driver is version 6.30.223.99 (I also tried version 6.31.223.1 before rolling back). The WLAN AutoConfig and ICS services are up and running.

Additional informations:

> C:\Windows\system32>netsh wlan show driver
>
> Interface name: WiFi
>
> ```
> Driver                    : Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter
> Vendor                    : Broadcom
> Provider                  : Broadcom
> Date                      : 27/05/2013
> Version                   : 6.30.223.99
> INF file                  : C:\Windows\INF\oem96.inf
> Files                     : 4 total
>                             C:\Windows\system32\DRIVERS\BCMWL63a.SYS
>                             C:\Windows\system32\bcmihvsrv64.dll
>                             C:\Windows\system32\bcmihvui64.dll
>                             C:\Windows\system32\drivers\vwifibus.sys
> Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
> Radio types supported     : 802.11n 802.11a 802.11g 802.11b
> FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
> 802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : Yes
> **Hosted network supported  : Yes**
> Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
>                             Open            None
>                             Open            WEP
>                             WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
>                             WPA2-Personal   TKIP
>                             WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
>                             WPA2-Personal   CCMP
>                             Vendor defined  Vendor defined
>                             Vendor defined  Vendor defined
>                             WPA-Enterprise  TKIP
>                             WPA-Personal    TKIP
>                             WPA-Enterprise  CCMP
>                             WPA-Personal    CCMP
> Authentication and cipher supported in ad-hoc mode:
>                             WPA2-Personal   CCMP
>                             Open            None
>                             Open            WEP
> IHV service present       : Yes
> IHV adapter OUI           : [00 10 18], type: [00]
> IHV extensibility DLL path: C:\Windows\System32\bcmihvsrv64.dll
> IHV UI extensibility ClSID: {aaa6dee9-31b9-4f18-ab39-82ef9b06eb73}
> IHV diagnostics CLSID     : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
> ```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: " but they aren't shown in "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections" no matter what I do" They are shown only when the hosted network is started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright after weeks of useless attempts to fix the problem I found a way out, not really a solution but upgrading to Windows 8.1 did the trick for me. Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

What might be causing an issue is having any Cisco VPN software installed.

Even if it is not currently running, I have noticed that once I uninstalled "Any Connect", I could get the hosted network running.